# "Rich is not defined" when trying to build an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made so code to build an embed for my Discord bot, but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  // Ignore messages that aren't from a guild
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith('$Commands')) {
    let Embed = new Rich.Embed;
    let Message = message.guild;
    let botEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("Commands From TTB")
      .setDescription("**Commands :**")
      .setColor("#4dff077")
      .setAuthorName("Galak$y#3038")
      .setAvatar("https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/563449221701959700/8386d5fe48d71898c40244e7a5a66d58.png")
      .addField("1. *Ban* = *Bans User Mentioned After Command* ``$ban <Mention User>``")
      .addField("2. Kick = Kicks User Mentioned After Command ``$kick <Mention User>``")
      .addField("3. what is myavatar = ``$what is my avatar``")
      .addFooter("New Commands Coming Soon...")
    return;
    message.channel.send(botEmbed)
  }
});
```

Here is the error:
[image: "Rich is not defined]

Comment: i don't want someone to ask why i put pics of the err or anything, just give me a answer to problem, or a new code

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not requiring you to put your code and errors as text and NOT images for no reason: those ways are better because it's way easier for people that have problems reading, or just for users that need to copy-paste your code/error. In the end, writing code as text makes people answer faster, because they spend less time on transcribing the images: remember that nobody pays us and you should at least help us solve your problem. For further info, please read this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embeds are created using the `RichEmbed` class constructor like so:

```js
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
```

When you declare `Embed` you're using `Rich.Embed`, and as it says, `Rich` is undefined.